# Получить массив свойства объекта в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

у меня есть string [] массив Arr содержащий объекты:

```
0: {PunktID: 19, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}
1: {PunktID: 20, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}
2: {PunktID: 21, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}
```

Я хочу получить из него массив свойства PunktID

```
[19,20,21]
```

Пробовал сделать через Object.value, но здесь вложенность второго уровня. Как можно по другому такое сделать?

Comment: Что есть "string []"? В приведенном примере я вижу объекты. Можете привести точный пример вашего массива объектов?

Comment: Не понял вопроса, у меня есть массив объектов
Arr: string[];

Comment: `Arr: string[]` это массив строк вида `Arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']`. То что привели вы, это не массив строк. Возможно эти 3 строки это элементы массива?

Comment: Заставили задуматься. В консоли Arr отображается таким образом, как я указал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш массив на самом деле должен выглядеть вот так:

```
const arr = [
  {PunktID: 19, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'},
  {PunktID: 20, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'},
  {PunktID: 21, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}
];
```

Это массив объектов. Цифры вам дорисовывает браузер в консоли разработчика.
Ниже 2 примера, как достать значения ключа **PunktID**

```js
const arr = [
  {PunktID: 19, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'},
  {PunktID: 20, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'},
  {PunktID: 21, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}
];

function ids(origin) {
  const res = [];
  origin.forEach(item => res.push(item.PunktID));
  return res;
}

function idsm(origin) {
  return origin.map(item => item.PunktID);
}

console.log(ids(arr));
console.log(idsm(arr));
```

P.S. Из комментариев:

> **arr: string[]** это аннотация typeScript, которая говорит, что переменная/ключ **arr** имеет тип данных массив **[]** строк **string**.
> Подробнее можно почитать на [официальном сайте](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятны изначальные условия.
Если речь про исходный массив объектов вида:

```
const arr = [
  {0: {PunktID: 19, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}}, 
  {1: {PunktID: 20, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}}, 
  {2: {PunktID: 21, PunktName: 'NAME1', Description: 'DESC1'}}
];
```

То можно пройтись через `map`

```
console.log(arr.map((item, i) => item[i].PunktID))  //[19,20,21]
```